# updating multiple variables with OFFSET command using INNER JOIN command

Tags: mysql

I need to edit this code:

```
UPDATE favorites SET category='$newcat',subcategory='$newsubcat',
sitename='$newwebsitename',
url='$newwebsiteurl' WHERE email='$email' ORDER BY favoritesid ASC LIMIT 1
```

to add: 'OFFSET 1' to the end, but because UPDATE does not allow the `OFFSET` command,
I need to use an `INNER JOIN` to add that part. however I only know how to do this 
when deleting single variables like:

```
DELETE a FROM favorites a
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT favoritesid
  FROM favorites
  WHERE email = '$email'
  ORDER BY favoritesid
  LIMIT 1 OFFSET x

 ) b ON a.favoritesid = b.favoritesid
```

but when updating multiple varibles, I wouldent even know where to start. can anyone help me out?

Comment: So what are you really trying to do with `OFFSET`.  Update a value from one row into adjacent row based on autoincrement id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
UPDATE favorites A INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT favoritesid FROM favorites WHERE email='$email'
    ORDER BY favoritesid LIMIT x
) B USING (favoritesid)
SET
    A.category='$newcat',
    A.subcategory='$newsubcat',
    A.sitename='$newwebsitename',
    A.url='$newwebsiteurl'
;
```

Here is another alternative:

```
UPDATE favorites A
SET
    A.category='$newcat',
    A.subcategory='$newsubcat',
    A.sitename='$newwebsitename',
    A.url='$newwebsiteurl'
WHERE A.favoritesid = 
(
    SELECT MAX(favoritesid) FROM favorites WHERE email='$email'
    ORDER BY favoritesid LIMIT x
);
```

These example assume OFFSET 0. If you have an OFFSET in mind, try this:

```
UPDATE favorites A INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT favoritesid FROM favorites WHERE email='$email'
    ORDER BY favoritesid LIMIT x OFFSET $myoffset
) B USING (favoritesid)
SET
    A.category='$newcat',
    A.subcategory='$newsubcat',
    A.sitename='$newwebsitename',
    A.url='$newwebsiteurl'
;
```

Comment: I am trying to UPDATE I was just using the delete as an example

Comment: I need to add the OFFEST in there somewhere